# Application runs, but there's no window

Tags: c#, wpf

C# noob here.

I'm trying to run a [C# project](http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/416/). It compiles, but when I execute the application, I can see it on the Task Manager, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

It's supposed to grab depth/color maps from the Kinect and display them.

Any ideas on how to start debugging this? I installed the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It isn't a C# project, it is not even C# code.  This is not a real question.

Comment: @Hans: the page linked to does mention a C# WPF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a new project, compile and run it, VS is fine.

If the downloaded app compiles and runs, the code is also fine.

If you're accessing hardware you may need to run Visual Studio with elevated privileges. (On the start menu, right click on the icon and "run as administrator")

If that doesn't work, check the VS output windows when you run it to see if there is anything that looks unusual. Alternatively set some breakpoints and step through the program to see where it's hanging.

Best thing would be to post on the originating forum.

Comment: +1 - thanks for  the methodology. It compiles, and runs. Adding breakpoints sound like a good idea.